# Contar repeticiones y ordenar los datos con Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, ordenamiento

tengo una duda: Debo contar cuantas veces se repiten los empleos de una columna "JobTitle" y elegir los 5 empleos que más se repiten, este es mi código:

```
cargos_comunes = sal.groupby(['JobTitle']).size().reset_index(name='Repeticiones')
cargos_comunes.sort_values(by=['Repeticiones'], ascending=False)

cargos_comunes
```

Y obtengo la siguiente salida:

```
    JobTitle    Repeticiones
0   ACCOUNT CLERK   83
1   ACCOUNTANT  5
2   ACCOUNTANT INTERN   48
3   ACPO,JuvP, Juv Prob (SFERS) 1
4   ACUPUNCTURIST   1
... ... ...
2154    X-RAY LABORATORY AIDE   26
2155    X-Ray Laboratory Aide   100
2156    YOUTH COMMISSION ADVISOR, BOARD OF SUPERVISORS  1
2157    Youth Comm Advisor  4
2158    ZOO CURATOR 1
```

Para la columna "Repeticiones", no me permite sacar los 5 empleos que más se repiten aún cuando realizó sort_values(). Mil gracias por su ayuda, o de que otra forma lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: No estas almacenando el dataframe ordenado haz `cargos_comunes = cargos_comunes.sort_values(by=['Repeticiones'], ascending=False)` y luego haces `cargos_comunes.head(5)`. Como recomendación utiliza `.count` y no `size`

Comment: Genial!!, ya me dejó, mil gracias